# When do we say that a function is double differentiable?

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

We say a function $g\colon\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable at $x$ iff there exists a linear map $A\colon\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ such that $\frac{\|g(x+h)-g(x)-Ah\|}{\|h\|}\xrightarrow{h\to0}0$. In other words, defining
$$\varepsilon_A(h):=\begin{cases}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)-Ah}{\|h\|}&\text{ if }h\ne0\\0&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$
$g$ is differentiable at $x$ iff there exists a linear map $A$ such that $\varepsilon_A$ is continuous at $0$.

> Can we say the same thing for double differentiability? In other words, defining
> $$\lambda_B(h):=\begin{cases}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)-h^\top\nabla g-\frac12h^\top Bh}{\|h\|^2}&\text{ if }h\ne0\\0&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$
> Can we say that the function $g$ is double differentiable at $x$ iff there exists a matrix $B$ such that $\lambda_B(h)$ is continuous at $0$?

Answer (score 0):

Actually we can talk about differentiale functions between Banach spaces by the same method. Suppose $F: V\to W$ is a continuous map between two Banach spaces. We say $F$ is **differentiable** at $x\in V$, if there exists a linear map $A: V\to W$ s.t.
$$
\lim_{V\ni h\to 0}\frac{\left\Vert F(x+h)-F(x)-Ah\right\Vert_W}{\left\Vert h\right\Vert_V} = 0.
$$
It can be shown that $A$ is unique if it exists, and we define $DF(x)=A$.

Using the above terminology, $F$ is twice differentiable means that the map $DF: V\to\mathcal{L}(V, W)$ is differentiable, here $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$ is the space of all linear maps from $V$ to $W$ endowed with the operator norm.

Comment: I understand neither Banach space nor operator norm. Are you saying that the answer to my question is yes, that the iff criterion I've written for double differentiability is valid?

Comment: @Martund It doesn't matter. If you are only interested in Euclidean spaces, you can just assume $V$ and $W$ to be Euclidean spaces and assume $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$ to be the space of matrices. All this are finite dimensional vector spaces, so you can just use the usual Euclidean norm. And I think your criterion is not quite right, $g(x)=e^{-1/x}\ (x > 0)$ and $g=0$ elsewhere is a counterexample. $g$ is infinitely differentiable at $x=0$ but your $\lambda_B(h)$ must blow up at $h=0$.

Comment: No it doesn't blow up at $0$. Taking $x=0$, we note that $g(0)=0, g'(0)=0$. Taking $B=0$, we get $\lambda_B(h)=g(h)/h^2$  which converges to $0$ as $h\to0$.

Comment: @Martund Emm... Maybe $h(x, y)=(g(x)+1)e^y$ will work.